# How can I resolve Babel error when transpiling optional chaining from mjs package in CRA React App?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-loader

I used `CRA` to create a React App and also to create a separate package. The `react-scripts` versions in the two modules are `4.0.2` and `5.0.0` respectively. Both are written in `Typescript`. I've made a habit of transpiling my packages to both `cjs` and `mjs`, so the package has both distributions.

Unfortunately, when I attempt to `react-scripts start` with the package included, `react-scripts` throws an error indicating that it cannot transpile an optionally chained method call. It also indicates that the React App is importing from the `mjs` distribution of the package.

I've tried upgrading the React App to `react-scripts@5.0.0`. This has lead to generalized chaos.

What can I try next?